# How to use node attributes in a shell script in CHEF recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have created a new CHEF Cookbook and in the attributes folder i have added the following value to the default attribute.rb file

    `********
    node.default['main']['a2'] = "hello world"
    ********`

In the chef recipe i would like to echo or create a new file with the name "hello world"

The recipe has the following lines:

## Cookbook Name:: a2

```
# Recipe:: default<br>
#<br>
# Copyright (c) 2018 The Authors, All Rights Reserved.<br>
execute 'just_test' do <br>
command 'touch /tmp/a2345' <br>
end <br>
execute 'just_test1' do <br>
command "touch /tmp/node['main']['a2']" <br>
end <br>
execute 'just_test2' do <br>
command "echo node['main']['a2']" <br>
end <br>
```

Although the recipe is successful, i do not see a file with "hello world"

`recipe: a2::default` 
`* execute[just_test] action run` 
`- execute touch /tmp/a2345` 
`* execute[just_test1] action run` 
`- execute touch /tmp/node['main']['a2']` 
`* execute[just_test2] action run` 
`- execute echo node['main']['a2']` 
`[2018-04-03T15:52:18+00:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because  override_runlist was given`

In the tmp directory the following files are created

a2345  node[main][a2]

How can we do attribute substitution in CHEF recipe???
Are there alternative to achieve this functionality

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should not use execute to create an empty file, use [file resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html).
2. Chef is written in Ruby and [follows Ruby string interpolation](https://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html). So, in your case it should be `"touch /tmp/#{node['main']['a2']}"` - outer double quotes are important.
3. Have you tried to go through our [official documentation?](https://learn.chef.io/). You could learn there about this and other useful 'cases'.